# Scrolling box with href not clickable

Tags: html, css, href

I have a div with a link in it (href)
The div is positioned in the right-bottom and it scrolls with the page.
But the problem is that the div is only clickable if you scroll to the bottom of the page.

this is the code:

```
<p style=" height: 60px; width: 220px; background-color: #0016fb; text-align: center; border-radius: 11px;bottom: 10px;right: 10px;position: fixed;">
<a  href=http://myurl.com/  style="color: white;" >some text..</a> </p>
```

Does anyone know why I can only click it when I scroll all the way down. And maybe a solution?

Kind regards

Comment: please share code Snipet or Js fiddle link.

Comment: Maybe another element's space it covering it up. Try adding `z-index` to the element.

Comment: Thanks! that was it :)

Answer (score 0):

As "Ahs N" have said, maybe another element (could be transparent) that also scrolls with the page is blocking that "element" with the link (`href=""`).

Try to find any element, similar to the element mentioned above, and try fixing CSS rules such as `z-index: ...`